# Create delegate with reference to method in DLL

Tags: c#, dll, delegates

I have DLL with some methods. I load it in runtime and I want to create delegate to method that is located in DLL.

DLL:

```
public static Point Play(int[,] foo, int bar, int baz) { ... }

// ...
```

I want to create delegate to the Play method. There may be more methods in the DLL.

Code:

```
private delegate Point PlayDel(int[,] foo, int bar, int baz);

// ...

Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFile(pathToMyDLL);
PlayDel dgt = // ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to find the type containing the method first, then use [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xw3bk13(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Type type = ass.GetType("NameOfTypeContainingMethod");
PlayDel del = (PlayDel) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(PlayDel), type, "Play");
```

Alternatively, you could get the `MethodInfo` and create the delegate from that:

```
Type type = ass.GetType("NameOfTypeContainingMethod");
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("Play");
PlayDel del = (PlayDel) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(PlayDel), method);
```

If there are multiple methods called `Play`, you may need to call `GetMethods()` instead and find the right one (e.g. by parameter types) first.